# Ошибка компиляции с ассемблерными вставками "Function call missing )"

Tags: c, windows, ассемблер, borland-c++

Работаю в программе Borland C++, пытаюсь написать программу на языке си с ассемблерной вставкой, но в разделах input и output вылетает ошибка. В данном случае ошибка приходится на строку 19 с кодом:

```
: "=r" (flags)
```

Там компилятор просит меня вставить скобку после знака ":". Я ставлю скобку, компилирую и снова в этом же месте требует скобку. Как исправить данную ошибку?

Ошибка:

```
Compiling

PROJECTS LAB2.C:

Error..PROJECTS LAB2.C 19: Function call missing )
```

Код программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned short flags = 0;

    // Устанавливаем биты 12-15 в 1 (соответствует МП 8086)
    flags |= 0xF000;

    // Ассемблерная вставка для проверки битов 12-15
    __asm__(
        "testw $0xF000, %0;" // Проверка битов 12-15
        "jz MP_80286;"      // Если биты 12-15 остаются 0, переход к MP_80286
        "jmp MP_80386;"     // В противном случае переход к MP_80386
        "MP_80286:;"
        "mov $0xF000, %0;"  // Если биты 12-15 были 0, установка в регистр флагов кода F000h
        "jmp done;"
        "MP_80386:;"
        "done:;"
        : "=r" (flags)
        : "0" (flags)
    );

    printf("Flags: %04X\n", flags);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Друг, ты бы написал, какой компилятор используешь? GCC справляется с этим кодом (прогнал через свой). Попробуй его - по ошибке явно, что компилятор и не ожидает двоеточий.

Если же ты и так его используешь:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Alternate-Keywords.html

Возможно, это твой вариант

Comment: Он написал - Borland C++

Comment: @MBo , виноват - думал, это IDE без компилятора